# Создать пул соединения с бд postgresql и библиотекой asyncpg

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

Имеется готовый файл с командами для базы данных.
Я не понимаю как создать пул и использовать его в функциях postgresql.
Для подключения имеются данные хоста, порт, логин и пароль.
Вот, собственно, код:

```
class DBComm:
    async def select(self, conn):
        values = await conn.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM users')
        a = dict(values)
        data = [f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in values.items()]
        # print(data)
        text = "\n".join(data)
        # print(text)
        return text

    async def db_new_user(conn, use=True, uses=1):
        user = types.User.get_current()
        user_id = user.id
        full_name = user.full_name
        args = (user_id, use, full_name)
        await conn.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, use, full_name, uses) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id',
                           user_id, use, full_name, uses)
        await conn.close()

    async def db_user_exists(conn):
        user = types.User.get_current()
        user_id = user.id
        result = await conn.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', user_id)
        result = int(result.replace('SELECT', ''))
        await conn.close()
        return bool(result)

    async def db_usage(conn):
        user = types.User.get_current()
        user_id = user.id
        await conn.execute('UPDATE users  SET uses = uses + 1 WHERE user_id = $1', user_id)
        await conn.close()

    async def db_get_info(info, conn):
        user_id = int(info)
        print("userid", user_id)
        rer = await conn.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1', user_id)
        a = dict(rer)
        data = [f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in rer.items()]
        # print(data)
        text = "\n".join(data)
        print(text)
        await conn.close()
        return text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания пула соединений в `asyncpg` имеется функция `create_pool` с [параметрами](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#connection-pools) которая возвращает экземпляр [пула](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.pool.Pool) соединений. В вашем случае можно добавить создание пула в `__init__` или вынести его в отдельный класс, если будет использоваться еще где то.

Пример:

```
class DBComm:
    def __init__(self, config: dict):
        self.pool = asyncpg.create_pool(**config)
        
    async def select(self):
        values = await self.pool.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM users') # пул сам выберет одно из доступных соединений
        a = dict(values)
        data = [f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in values.items()]
        # print(data)
        text = "\n".join(data)
        # print(text)
        return text
```

Вы можете явно получать соединение из пула методом `con = pool.acquire()` и возвращать его `pool.release(con)`. Разумеется можно все делать с использованием контекстного менеджера.